# Checking for object existence with same m2m relation in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model Teacher like this:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
```

And Course model:

```
course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
```

While creating Teacher object I want to make sure that the new object I am creating should not have same courses(m2m relation) with any other existing Teacher object.

For example if Teacher object A has **English,Maths,History** m2m Course relation, So no new Teacher object can have **English,Maths,History**.

**View**

```
def AddTeacher(request):
    #id's are the courses object id
    id1 = request.POST.get('id1')
    id2 = request.POST.get('id2')
    id3 = request.POST.get('id3')


    Tobject  = Teacher(name="temp")
    Tobject.save()

    for i in [id1,id2,id3]:
        Cobject = Course.objects.get(id=i)
        Tobject.course.add(Cobject )
    Tobject.name = "Teacher"+str(Tobject.id)
    Tobject.save()

    temp = {}
    temp['message'] = "Object created successfully"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(temp),mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: Can you please add your views.py code where you save the teacher so I can see how the data is collected and how the objects are created?

Comment: I have updated my code .Please tell me how can I check

Comment: where does 'Sobject' object come from?

Comment: Sorry @juankysmith I updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems relatively simple. Just do a query for a teacher with all the course IDs specified in `request.POST` and bail if there are any results:

```
def AddTeacher(request):
    #id's are the courses object id
    id1 = request.POST.get('id1')
    id2 = request.POST.get('id2')
    id3 = request.POST.get('id3')

    if Teacher.objects.filter(course=id1).filter(course=id2).filter(course=id3).count() > 0:
        return HttpResponseForbidden("Can't add a teacher with these courses; one already exists")

    # ... function continues
```

This addresses the precise case in your question; if you want to deal with situations where the specified courses are a sub-set of an existing teacher's courses (if you decide to allow adding a teacher with two courses, for instance) more thought will be needed.

Comment: Great, Thanks..But would it take much more time for this query to execute or is it fine?

Comment: I'm not sure if Django is smart enough to realise this query can be done without a `JOIN`, but even if not we're still talking about a single query with 3 `WHERE` conditions: this is definitely at the lower end of the gnarly queries spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

OK here it goes

```
def AddTeacher(request):
    #id's are the courses object id
    id1 = request.POST.get('id1')
    id2 = request.POST.get('id2')
    id3 = request.POST.get('id3')

    qs = Teacher.objects.all()

    #Build a dynamic filter query
    qs = reduce(lambda q, c: q.filter(course=c), [c for c in [id1, id2, id3]], qs)

    if qs:
        raise ValueError("A teacher with the selected courses already exists")

    teacher  = Teacher(name="temp")
    teacher.save()

    for i in [id1, id2, id3]:
        course = Course.objects.get(id=i)
        teacher.course.add(course)
    teacher.name = "Teacher"+str(teacher.id)
    teacher.save()

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
        'message': 'Object created successfully'
    }), mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: qs = reduce(lambda q, c: q.filter(course=c), c for c in [id1,id2,id3], qs) has some syntax error "expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument"

Comment: No its not working, i am able to add multiple objects with same m2m relations.qs is always empty so it always creates new object with same m2m relation.:(

Comment: you will have to check why qs is always empty. How does a valid id1 parameter look like? What does it contain?

Comment: Ok .BUt Thanks a  lot @Mikael for helping me...So nice of you :)

Comment: @Mikael, check out PEP8, the [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Having variables like `Vobject` instead of `variable` is also a bit confusing...

Comment: Thanks @supervacou, I was using the same code/variables as the person asking the question, only adding my suggested solution. I would not use VObject etc. in my own code. (Although a queryset named qs is not very pretty either :) )

Answer (score 0):

In a related answer but not exactly for this case, you can check if an object is in a m2m with:

```
if english_course in teacher.courses.all():
    # already in there :)
```

I just thought it was a nice way to do it.